# OpenGL ES 2 tetrahedron with colored faces

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning OpenGL ES 2 for a directed study and there are some things i'm not understanding.  I don't quite understand what stride is that is passed to glVertexAttribPointer.  Also i was able to draw a solid color tetrahedron, but now i'm trying to expand it to make every face a different color.  It is not going well.  Could someone help with what i'm doing wrong in terms of the shaders and why it draws the colors funky/doesn't rotate right.  I was using http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-two-ambient-and-diffuse-lighting/ as a base for understanding how drawing works.  Any help with understanding how shaders work and the stride and so forth and what i'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.lab5task1;

//middle of screen is 0,0.  To left/right is -/+ x, up/down is +/- y

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{

private static final String TAG = "MyGLRenderer";
private Tetrahedron mTet;
private float height, width;
public float xTouch, yTouch;
Random rand = new Random();

private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16]; //model view and projection matrix
private final float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16]; //projection matrix
private final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16]; //view matrix
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16]; //rotation matrix
private float[] drawColor = { rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), 1f };
private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
MyGLRenderer(Context context)
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    //used for correct drawing and touch
    this.height = size.y;
    this.width = size.x;
    this.xTouch = this.yTouch = 0;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config)
{

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Use culling to remove back faces.
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Enable depth testing
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //eye positions
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = -3f;

    // We are looking toward the distance
    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = -1.0f;

    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera position.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
{

    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;
    float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / 10000.0f) * ((int) time);

    mTet = new Tetrahedron();

    // Draw the triangle facing straight on.
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, .5f, .5f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    mTet.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
{
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode)
{

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public static void checkGlError(String glOperation)
{
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
}

class Tetrahedron
{

enum STYLE
{
    OLD, NEW
};

private STYLE codeType = STYLE.NEW;

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final FloatBuffer mColors;
private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
private int mMVMatrixHandle;

private final String vertexShaderCode = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" + " attribute vec4 vPosition;" + "void main() {" + "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" + "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;" + "uniform vec4 vColor;" + "void main() {" + "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" + "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
// 72d angles at center, 108 angle at vertex
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static final int COLOR_DATA_SIZE = 4;

static float tetCoords[] = { 0.0f, 0.622008459f, 0.0f,//
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,//
        0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,//
        0.0f, 0.0f, .622008459f };

static float colors[] = {
        //face one
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//             
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
        //face two
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//             
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
        //face three
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//             
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//
        //face four
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//             
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//
};

String[] attributes = { "a_Position", "a_Color" };

private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1 };
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
private final int colorStride = COLOR_DATA_SIZE * 4;

float color[] = { .5f, .5f, .5f, 1f };

public Tetrahedron()
{
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates

    //this.color = color;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            tetCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(tetCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    mColors = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer();
    mColors.put(colors);
    mColors.position(0);

    if (codeType == STYLE.NEW)
    {

        final String vertexShader = getVertexShader();
        final String fragmentShader = getFragmentShader();

        int vertexShaderHandle = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
        int fragmentShaderHandle = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShader);
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShaderHandle);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShaderHandle);
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++)
        {
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgram, i, attributes[i]);
        }

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }
    else
    {
        int vertexShaderHandle = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShaderHandle = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShaderHandle);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShaderHandle);
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++)
        {
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgram, i, attributes[i]);
        }

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }
}

protected String getVertexShader()
{

    // TODO: Explain why we normalize the vectors, explain some of the vector math behind it all. Explain what is eye space.
    final String vertexShader = "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n" // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.
            + "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;       \n" // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.  
            + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n" // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
            + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n" // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.
            + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n" // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

            + "void main()                    \n" // The entry point for our vertex shader.
            + "{                              \n"
            // Transform the vertex into eye space.
            + "   vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);              \n"
            // Multiply the color by the illumination level. It will be interpolated across the triangle.
            + "   v_Color = a_Color;                                       \n"
            // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
            // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.       
            + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;                            \n" + "}                                                                     \n";

    return vertexShader;
}

protected String getFragmentShader()
{
    final String fragmentShader = "precision mediump float;       \n" // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                                                                      // precision in the fragment shader.                
            + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n" // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the 
                                                  // triangle per fragment.             
            + "void main()                    \n" // The entry point for our fragment shader.
            + "{                              \n" + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;     \n" // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.          
            + "}                              \n";

    return fragmentShader;
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix)
{
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    if (codeType == STYLE.NEW)
    {
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_MVPMatrix");
        mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_MVMatrix");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Position");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Color");
        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Pass in the color information
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, COLOR_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                colorStride, mColors);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    }
    else
    {

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    }

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
            drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness you need to post so much less code. Try to limit yourself to a directly relevant snippet of code that directly exposes your problems. Nobody is going to want to read through hundreds of lines to find an error.

Comment: Well most of the code was relevant in terms of figuring this out i felt.  I didn't know if the setLookAt needed to be changed, the shaders, or something just in the class

Comment: At the very least leave out the imports, attributes, and large commented out portions of code that can definitionally not be relevant. That's about a third to a half of what you posted.

Comment: Ok i'll make sure not to include imports and stuff anymore.  Don't variable declarations and comments help others looking at my code for help though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stride is the distance between attributes in bytes, and is used if you are packing more than one attribute into the same array. It seems that you're using one array per attribute here, so you could pass in 0 as the stride to tell OpenGL that the attributes are tightly packed.

Your position and color arrays should be the same length in terms of components. i.e. one position for one color. This is probably why the colors are not coming out as you expect.

If you want each face to be a different, solid, color, setup the vertices so that each triangle is distinct, and draw with GL_TRIANGLES. For example:

```
{ 0f, 1f, 0f,    // Left
  -1, 0f, 1f,
  -1, 0f, -1f,

  0f, 1f, 0f,    // Right
  1f, 0f, 1f,
  1f, 0f, 1f,

  0f, 1f, 0f,    // Near 
 -1f, 0f, 1f,
  1f, 0f, 1f,

  0f, 1f, 0f,    // Far 
 -1f, 0f, -1f,
  1f, 0f, -1f }
```

and draw with GL_TRIANGLES. Let us know if this leads to an improvement!

Comment: I tried that and it produces a 2D triangle http://oi39.tinypic.com/2d94iub.jpg where 1 face has 2 read and 1 green vertex, and the other face is all red.

Comment: Scratch above i didn't do it quite right.  It almost works, i put GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12); but some of the faces don't seem to be connected/not showing up still

Comment: It could be the coordinates. Try to go down to 1 triangle (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3), and see if that works. Then increase to 12, checking that the data for each triangle is OK. It might help to draw it out on a paper (seriously! That method has worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

You're passing 4 vertices, and 12 colours. You're specifying 1 vec4 colour for verts 0-11, and only drawing triangles between indices 0-3, so only the first 4 of your colours are being used.

Comment: That makes sense, so is there a way i can attach different colors to each face of the vertex instead of just 1 color to each vertex so i can get faces that are just one color instead of multi colored like this: http://oi42.tinypic.com/15e8y6t.jpg
while using TRIANGLE_STRIP

Comment: Because the colour used in the fragment shader is a "varying", i.e. it is the result of interpolating the values from the 3 vertices which make up the face, the only way you can have faces with their own block colours, is to duplicate the vertices that compose it such that they contribute a different colour to each face they belong to. So the corner of a cube might belong to 6 triangles in total, so it would need to be duplicated 6 times, each occurrence having its own colour. Basically I don't think it's possible to do what you want with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, but the other answers here work.